# Option clash xeCJK and fontspec

Tags: fontspec, xecjk, japanese

I need to load the `fontspec` package with the `no-math` option while also loading the `xeCJK` package to include a few Japanese names in a large English document. Since the`xeCJK` package already loads the `fontspect` package without any options, I am running into problems. More precisely, the code

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}
  角谷静夫
\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

results in an option clash for the `fontspec` package whereas the code

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{xeCJK}

\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}
  角谷静夫
\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

results in the following error:

```
 LaTeX Error: Environment CJK undefined.
```

Is there a way around this? I would also be happy with a solution to include snippets of Japanese using other packages than `xeCJK`.

Answer (score 1):

The `fontspec` should be loaded before `xeCJK` if `no-math`. And the `CJK` environment is not provided by `xeCJK` and thus should be omitted.

A minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Hiragino Mincho ProN}
\begin{document}
角谷 静夫
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does the above document have English as main language?

Answer (score 0):

A rather primitive workaround is to just load a suitable Japanese font using `fontspec`. Of course this way the additional typesetting capabilities of the `xeCJK` package cannot be used. The resulting code would be as follows:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\cjkfont{HanaMinA}

\begin{document}
{\cjkfont 角谷 静夫}
\end{document}
```